# Selenium IDE `select` command fails to locate element - whose ID was filled automatically by the IDE

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-ide

**My problem:** I'm failing to select an element in Selenium IDE, even though the target ID is filled automatically by the IDE.

**Problem description:**
In http://instantsearchplus.myshopify.com/, I want to type in the `search` field (top right).

This is the HTML code for the search field:

```
<input name="q" value="" aria-label="Search our store" 
class="header-bar__search-input ui-autocomplete-input" 
autocomplete="OfF" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"
id="input_id_0_suggestor_007" isp_ac="OfF" type="search">
```

So, I enter the `select` Command, and after clicking on the *search field*, Selenium IDE automatically fills the Target with `id=input_id_0_suggestor_007.`

All is well, right? 
*Wrong!*

When I try to run the script, I get the error

```
[info] Playing test case Untitled 2
[info] Executing: |open | / | |
[info] Executing: |select | id=input_id_0_suggestor_007 | |
[error] Element id=input_id_0_suggestor_007 not found
[info] Test case failed
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Note: I tried various `select` related commands (`select,` `selectFrame,` `selectWindow,` etc. ) with a variety of possible `targets` (`id,` `name,` `css,` etc. ) - but did not find any combination that works. `Click` also didn't work.

The HTML code around the search field:

```
<div class="header-bar">
  <div class="wrapper medium-down--hide">
    <div class="large--display-table">
      <div class="header-bar__left large--display-table-cell">            
      </div>    
      <div class="header-bar__right large--display-table-cell">
        <div class="header-bar__module">
          <a href="/cart" class="cart-toggle">
            <span class="icon icon-cart header-bar__cart-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Cart
            <span class="cart-count header-bar__cart-count">2</span>
          </a>
        </div>                                
          <div class="header-bar__module header-bar__search">
            <form action="/pages/search-results" method="get" role="search">                  
              <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="isp_polite_powered_by_id ui-helper-hidden-accessible">Powered by InstantSearch+ <a href="http://www.instantsearchplus.com">Site Search Autocomplete</a></span><input name="q" value="" aria-label="Search our store" class="header-bar__search-input ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="OfF" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" id="input_id_0_suggestor_007" isp_ac="OfF" type="search">
              <button type="submit" class="btn icon-fallback-text header-bar__search-submit">
                <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="fallback-text">Search</span>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>            
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper large--hide">
    <button type="button" class="mobile-nav-trigger" id="MobileNavTrigger">
      <span class="icon icon-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Menu
    </button>
    <a href="/cart" class="cart-toggle mobile-cart-toggle">
      <span class="icon icon-cart header-bar__cart-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Cart <span class="cart-count">2</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul id="MobileNav" class="mobile-nav large--hide">

  <li class="mobile-nav__link" aria-haspopup="true">        
      <a href="/" class="mobile-nav">
        Home
      </a>        
  </li>            
  <li class="mobile-nav__link" aria-haspopup="true">        
      <a href="/search" class="mobile-nav">
        Search page
      </a>        
  </li>            
  <li class="mobile-nav__link" aria-haspopup="true">        
      <a href="http://instantsearchplus.myshopify.com/pages/search-results/collections-accessories" class="mobile-nav">
        Accessories
      </a>        
  </li>            
  <li class="mobile-nav__link" aria-haspopup="true">        
      <a href="http://instantsearchplus.myshopify.com/pages/search-results/collections-best-seller" class="mobile-nav">
        Best Seller
      </a>        
  </li>            
  <li class="mobile-nav__link" aria-haspopup="true">        
      <a href="http://instantsearchplus.myshopify.com/pages/search-results/collections-gloves" class="mobile-nav">
        Gloves
      </a>        
  </li>            
  <li class="mobile-nav__link" aria-haspopup="true">        
      <a href="/pages/about-us" class="mobile-nav">
        About us
      </a>        
  </li>                      
</ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: `ClickAt //input` works.

Answer (score 0):

> ClickAt //input works

Indeed, select command is usually meant for selecting options from a select tag.
Here's a quote from the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#Select-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)

> Constructor. A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag. If it is not, then an UnexpectedTagNameException is thrown.

Comment: The problem is that *only* `ClickAt //input` works. Namely, trying to use `ClickAt` with the other options the Selenium IDE offers - fail.

Comment: hmm. Please help me understand correctly, you want to type some values in the input box, or just move the cursor there?